# wix find whether prerequisites are installed after feature selection tree (customizedlg)

Tags: wix

I am creating an installer using wix. My installer installs 2 features.

- Feature 1 depends on Prerequisite-1
- Feature 2 depends on Prerequisite-2

As part of installation when the user selects Feature 1 from the Feature selection tree(customizedlg), and presses Next, i want to check whether the prerequisite for Feature 1 is installed. If not i want to abort the installation.

I can find the prerequisite using RegistrySearch.

How to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need custom actions here, and you should not move the prerequisites check after the feature selection.

Instead, let it go its usual way. Use `RegistrySearch` to detect whether your two prerequisites are installed. As a result, you'll have two properties - `PREREQ1INSTALLED` and `PREREQ2INSTALLED` - set. Make your feature conditions dependent on these properties, and the user will simply not be able to select the one which is disabled.

If you only have these 2 features, and hence at least one should be available for installation, make a launch condition to check that at least one of those prerequisites is installed:

```
<Condition>PREREQ1INSTALLED OR PREREQ2INSTALLED</Condition>
```

Answer (score 2):

To check prerequisite after feature selection, you can use a custom action. In this custom action you can check if the feature is selected and according to that you can use Registry Search to get the details of prerequisite and preform action accordingly.

For getting all the feature in custom action you can use this code sample:

```
 foreach (FeatureInfo fi in session.Features)
 {
     if (fi.RequestState == InstallState.Local || fi.RequestState == InstallState.Source || fi.RequestState == InstallState.Default)
     {           
         if (fi.Name == "Feature1")
         {
             //check for prerequisite for Feature1
         }
         if (fi.Name == "JobService")
         {
             //check for prerequisite for Feature2
         }
     }
}
```

If prerequisite is not installed then set some session variable to show message on the UI